# IP to CIDR conversion

Tags: ip, range, cidr

I got this exercise in which I need to convert the following range of directions to CIDR:

160.65.0.0 -161.127.255.255

My try is:

**1010000**0.01000001.0.0 - **1010000**1.01111111.0.0-> **160.65.0.0/7**

However, when I calculate my network 160.65.0.0/7 in an online site, it gives me this:

- First IP: 160.0.0.1
- Last IP: 161.255.255.254

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do that, you need to divide it in 2 blocks:

160.65.0.0 - 160-255.255.255

161.0.0.0  - 161.127.255.255

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are wrong, who said 161.127.255.255 is the last network in this range?

161.127.255.255 is simply inside this range.

Comment: It is in the problem definition. I think I might be right as well, but that is bothering me.